# PHP secure image without affecting performance

Tags: php, image, apache, security

I know that apache is extremely fast delivering static files due to some magic that I'm not completely certain of but had something to do with the OS directly.

I need to serve some images but only to authorized users, is there any way I can verify a user and then tell php to tell apache to serve the image as it would if it weren't invoking PHP?

I hope what I'm saying makes sense...

Comment: Hw about if the image is loaded into the PHP file and output withthe correct headers so that the php file can "validate" the user before displaying any image. A gateway. This will be less fast but will be much more secure.

Comment: Or can you clarify how you authenticate the user

Comment: @Martin it has to be based on session. I am aware of how to implement it securely, the purpose of the question is if I could make it as efficient as (or at least close to) apache static file delivery.